# How to Re-Index or Remove Old Google Drive Folders in Google Plus Photos/Picasa

Tags: sync, google-drive, picasa, google-plus

I have ~10GB of photos on my Google Drive, which is sync'd across multiple computers with no issues whatsoever. I'm pretty organised and have things categorised and named relatively sanely.

I've also recently discovered Google+, and like the idea that I can use the same storage quota to selectively share my images. I flipped the magic switch that allows Google Drive images to be used in Google Plus, and lo and behold they appear.

However I've since done some reorganisation, but the folders haven't synchronised between Drive and Plus Photos (aka Picasa). There's duplicate/empty albums all over the place, and I really don't want to have to sift through over 150 folders and try to work out which is the right copy and which is the duplicate (some folders have different numbers of images, despite being duplicates of each other - go figure!).

My question: **Can you force Google Photos/Picasa to re-index or re-import your Google Drive directory?**

Comment: I'm not using Drive or Photos, but can you unflip "the magic switch", wait for Photos to clear up, then re-flip?

Comment: Have you enabled [sync to web](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/106176?hl=en)?

Comment: It seems that the issue has solves itself - the original duplications were as a result of cached objects in Drive that were still in Plus' index.

Closest answer was harrymc - would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can award the bounty?

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to disconnect Google Drive from Google Plus Photos, so to
clear out all folders, then re-establish the connection for an up-to-date index.